# Aruba 2930M - the NTP server is unreachable

Tags: switch, ntp, aruba

My Aruba 2930M switch cant reach the NTP servers.

Below is the following conf:

```
    #####################

    OOBM
```

IP Address  192.168.90.34

IP Version  IPV4

IP Mode Manual

Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0

Gateway 192.168.90.1

DEFAULT_VLAN

IP Config:  Manual

IP Address: 192.168.2.107

IPv4 Default Gateway:   192.168.2.1

IPv4 Subnet Mask:   255.255.255.0

```
    ###############
```

[image]

Comment: Can the switch ping 192.168.46.148? Does the server actually work?

Comment: I've never used an Aruba device but, in Cisco devices when you enable `ip routing` you can no longer use a default gateway statement and have to use a route statement instead.  If that's true for Aruba devices as well, you look to be missing something like `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's poorly documented but Jesse's hit the nail on the head:

> The switch uses the IP default gateway only while operating as a Layer
> 2 device. While routing is enabled on the switch, the IP default
> gateway is not used.

from https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c04725294

So, you'll need to add

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't want to do the research earlier to confirm since I was busy working.

Comment: Should i add 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 or a real IP?

Comment: The command is `ip route <network address> <network mask> <gateway>`, so `0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` is the network/mask that fits any destination address - the default route. Just add it like that.

Comment: I added the (ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1) but still have the NTP server is unreachable message

Comment: Again: can the switch ping that IP address? Have you verified the server is working and accepting queries?

Comment: there is a ping test in the Switch , I cant ping the NTP server from it

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the IP config. Please add the complete config to your question. You should sanitize any sensitive information, e.g. public IP addresses or admin details. Does the NTP server have a (default) route that includes the switch?

Comment: I did updated the full configuration

Comment: Can the switch ping its default gateway? Anything beyond?

Comment: no , it says its unreachable!

Comment: Then you've got a network problem, totally unrelated to NTP. You need to make sure that the switch can ping its gateway and vice versa. You'll need to add detail information about your network and devices (type, config) to your question, otherwise we won't be able to solve your problem.